# The development Server returned response error code : 500 react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am simply trying to run a `react-native app.`using the android on ubuntu. Now, Here I have used `react-native init`.
Here, I have just created a project and just tried with the command

```
react-native run-android
```

After this I am getting an error on the simulator ,

The development server returned response error code: 500

```
URL: http://Ip:8081/index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false

Body:
{"type":"TransformError","lineNumber":0,"errors":[{"description":"/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/index.js: Couldn't find preset \"module:metro-react-native-babel-preset\" relative to directory \"/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject\"","lineNumber":0}],"name":"SyntaxError","message":"/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/index.js: Couldn't find preset \"module:metro-react-native-babel-preset\" relative to directory \"/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject\"","stack":"Error: Couldn't find preset \"module:metro-react-native-babel-preset\" relative to directory \"/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject\"\n    at /home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:293:19\n    at Array.map (native)\n    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)\n    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:264:10)\n    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:249:14)\n    at OptionManager.init (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)\n    at File.initOptions (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)\n    at new File (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)\n    at Pipeline.transform (/home//ProjectWork/native/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)"}
processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:266
access$200
    BundleDownloader.java:35
onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:153
execute
    RealCall.java:135
run
    NamedRunnable.java:32
runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162
run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636
run
    Thread.java:764
```

SO, I am not understanding this error.

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "android": "react-native run-android"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.50.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My `.bablerc`

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Can any one help me with this issue ?

Comment: Did you check what your metro builder shows? Probably a typo or something.

Comment: that babelpreset works with the new version of react-native. try to update react-native

Comment: It was already at the new version, but it was giving another errors.

Comment: @SamithaNanayakkara Could you please tell me how do I check that

Comment: When you execute the react-native run-android, it will automatically open another terminal which is metro builder. Mostly it would be automatically started in MacOS. But in windows or linux you have to manually execute react-native start in another terminal according to my experience.